# Python string matching using 'in'

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary, boolean-expression

I have encountered a problem with string matching; for example, searching for `".txt" in "myfile.txt".lower()` being found sometimes but not others. If I run the program once, the match is not found, only to be found on the next run.

I suspect the problem lies within the nested for loops. Can anyone spot the error (and perhaps even advise on a cleaner & more efficient way to achieve this)?

```
def find_string_in_filename_and_move(dir_filelist_dict, string_dict):
    """
    Iterates through files in directories, for each file searches for strings
    Moves file to new folder if string matches
    :param dir_filelist_dict: dict of dirs with associated file list
    :param string_dict: dict or strings with associated home dir
    :return: None
    """
    for dir_name, files in dir_filelist_dict.items():
        for search_string, folder in string_dict.items():
            for f in files:
                if search_string in f.lower():  # problem encountered here
                    old_path = path.join(dir_name, f)
                    new_path = path.join(dir_name, folder)
                    if not path.isdir(new_path):
                        mkdir(new_path)
                    move(old_path, new_path)
                    dir_filelist_dict[dir_name].remove(f)
    return None
```

Comment: to be sure, I would do `if search_string.lower() in f.lower()`, and I would print them first to see what's going on. You're doing some file/dir moving afterwards. Maybe that your cached filelists are not updated properly in some cases, leading to strange effects.

Comment: Well the loop seems correct to me, as Jean Francois says the issue could be in how you scan those files, there could be a cache and also I would take a look at how file names are encoded